# CORS on GAE AppRTC clone

Tags: python, google-app-engine, cors, webrtc, apprtcdemo

I installed a clone of the AppRTC GAE application, but I have a CORS problem with the response that comes from the TURN server.

I have installed my own TURN server on a VPS, but the problem with the CORS request continues and I have no idea how to fix it.

https://github.com/webrtc/apprtc

I have tried to modify the python request to add the necessary header, but with no luck.

Also I found this resource regarding CORS support
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/config/appconfig

but still no luck.

The error I'm getting is 
`XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://computeengineondemand.appspot.com/turn?username=910605201&key=4080218913. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://hubert-rtc.appspot.com' is therefore not allowed access.`

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you solve the problem?

Comment: Yes, I exposed an api on my server, which only makes a request to GCM and returns the result. was the fastest way for me..

Answer (score 0):

AppRtc has purposefully disabled CORS for fetching the turnServer address. They expect developers to have their own TurnServer.

https://github.com/webrtc/apprtc/issues/175